# How can I pass the value of an input in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass the LoadNumber into a php file to use in a query and result in a FPDF on a button click. the button works but the value its passing is $(' not the value I wanted. Where am I going wrong. Here is my code.

```
$(location.href="dispatch.php? LoadNumber=$('#LoadNumber').val()")};
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense.

Comment: You can always create html form and submit that value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
// Get the LoadNumber value first
var value = $('#LoadNumber').val();

// Set the url with query string properly
var url = "dispatch.php?LoadNumber=" + value ;    

// Re-direct to the url now
location.href = url;
```

Just to make things clear for you.

This can also be done in one line like:

```
location.href = "dispatch.php?LoadNumber=" + $('#LoadNumber').val();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was close the quote at the end is what was messing me up. Well that and the missing +.

Comment: I went back and changed that part as well but it worked with it there.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in this way :

```
$(location.href="dispatch.php? LoadNumber="+$('#LoadNumber').val())};
```

Don't put $('#LoadNumber') in quotes.

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks. Looking at the answers below is one way better then another? I'm learning this on the fly. I'm self taught and my teacher is a fool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set that value to `location.href`, just write the following:

```
location.href = "dispatch.php?LoadNumber=" + $('#LoadNumber').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = 'dispatch.php?LoadNumber=' + $('#LoadNumber').val();
```